# Probability question- expectancy of number of squares in a graphed paper

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'd love to get help in this probability question-

you are given a graphed paper size 2n * 2n, each single square (1 * 1) has a probability of p to be colored in black independently of other squares (otherwise the single square is white).

a monochromatic square is a square size 2 * 2 that each of its' 1*1 squares are the same color (black or white).
Let Y be a random variable that counts the number of monochromatic squares in the paper.
Show that-

E(Y)=(2n-1)^2 * (p^2 + (1-p)^2)

By what they request from me to prove I assume I first need to show that there are (2n-1)^2 such squares in a 2n * 2n graphed paper (I tried induction but it seems to complicated so I'd love to get advice on that as well); however each 2 * 2 square contains 4 small 1*1 sqaures so why isn't it (p^4 + (1-p)^4) in the other brackets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I suspect you are correct about the $(p^4+(1-p)^4)$ term

Comment: Consider how many positions there are for the top left corner of a $2\times 2$ square: every little square except for the bottom row or right side